# Data in local .mdf file didn't changed, but no error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I use a `.mdf` file as my database. I also used Linq-to-SQL connection.

At first, my application can add and display the data in the `.mdf` file correctly. But when I try to see the data by clicking the `.mdf` file directly and from the table, the database is empty.

I've set the `.mdf` file and the `.dbml` file `Copy if newer`, but still nothing.

Please help me and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I bet your connection string contains

```
AttachDbFileName=somefilename.mdf
```

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...